# Jasmin + karma: "Error: Unexpected value 'HttpClient' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation."

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using jasmine as a test framework and karma as a test runner. I'm trying to create an HttpClient object so I could create a service that as a depedency to this object:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [HttpClient],
    imports: [HttpClient],
    providers: [HttpClient]
});
TestBed.get(HttpClient);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Unexpected value 'HttpClient' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Follows all the code:

```
import { I18nService } from "../../services/i18n.service";
import { TestBed, inject, async } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { EditionHistoryEventsModel } from "./dropdown.edition.history.events.model";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { TestUtil } from "../../utils/test.uti";



describe('DropDownEditionHistoryItemModel', () => {
    let i18nService: I18nService;
     
    beforeAll(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [HttpClient],
            imports: [HttpClient],
            providers: [HttpClient]
        });
        i18nService = TestUtil.geti18nService(TestBed.get(HttpClient));
    });
    it('asdasd', () => {
        let model: EditionHistoryEventsModel = new EditionHistoryEventsModel(i18nService);
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The compilation error you get is thrown when you try to include something other than a component, directive, or pipe in the `declarations` array.

I've refactored your test spec to remove the `HttpClient` from the declarations module, import the `HttpClientTestingModule` since it has some significant advantages over the `HttpClientModule` for [testing](https://medium.com/netscape/testing-with-the-angular-httpclient-api-648203820712), and used a slightly different pattern to create an instance of your `I18nService` to pass to your model class.

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

    describe('TestSpec', () => {

    let intlService = I18nService;

    beforeAll(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [],
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [I18nService]
    });

    i18nService = TestBed.Get(I18nService);
});
```

Comment: I was running a build/test on a Jenkins pipeline (agent OS RHEL8) this fixed my issue with the matching error.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the error resolved when I imported Overlay Module

```
import {OverlayModule} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
...

   beforeAll(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [...],
            imports: [OverlayModule],
            providers: [...]
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to import HttpClientModule in your module file

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```