# Angular Testing - how to test Data Service with extended base class

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, jestjs, angular-test

I'm having a hard to setup Tests of my Data Services, I'm trying to use the `HttpClientTestingModule` as defined in these articles [Testing with the Angular HttpClient API](https://medium.com/netscape/testing-with-the-angular-httpclient-api-648203820712), from this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116993/jasmin-karma-error-unexpected-value-httpclient-imported-by-the-module-dy/52133396) and also tried `inject` from this article [Testing HttpClient](https://alligator.io/angular/testing-httpclient/) but I can't get it to work.

I believe my problems comes from the fact that I have a global `DataService` which uses 3 service providers (`HttpClient`, [NGXLogger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-logger) and [TranslateService](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core) from `ngx-translate`). Then I have multiple Data Services which extends the global `DataService` like so

```
@Injectable()
export class UserDataService extends DataService {
  constructor(protected http: HttpClient, protected logger: NGXLogger, protected translate: TranslateService) {
  super(http, logger, translate);
  this.url = `api/users`;
}

getUsers(): Observable<Users[]> {
  return super.getAll<User[]>(this.url);
}
```

So as you can see, each extended data services (like `UserDataServices`) takes care of injecting the 3 necessary dependencies to the `super` call.

I'm trying to code my test, which is done with `Jest`, with the following code

```
describe('User Data Service', () => {
  let dataService: TemplateDataService;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        LoggerModule.forRoot({ level: NgxLoggerLevel.ERROR, serverLoggingUrl: 'api/logging', serverLogLevel: NgxLoggerLevel.ERROR }),
      ],
      providers: [
        UserDataService
      ]
    });
    dataService = TestBed.get(UserDataService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

it('should return an Observable<User[]>', () => {
  const dummyUsers = [
    { login: 'John' },
    { login: 'Doe' }
  ];

  dataService.getAll().subscribe((users: User[]) => {
    expect(users.length).toBe(2);
    expect(users).toEqual(dummyUsers);
  });

  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(`api/users`);
  expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
  req.flush(dummyUsers);
});
```

and it keeps throwing the following error

```
Unexpected value 'HttpClientModule' imported by the module 'HttpClientTestingModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

I also tried with this piece of code, but I get the same error

```
it(
  'should get users',
  inject(
    [HttpTestingController, NGXLogger, TranslateService, DataService],
    (
      httpMocker: HttpTestingController,
      logger: NGXLogger,
      translate: TranslateService,
      dataServicer: DataService
    ) => {
      // ...our test logic here
    }
  )
);
```

I'm fairly new to Unit Testing (I started last week) and I'm totally blocked with testing any of my Data Services (on the bright side, I'm ok with testing the component with a data service mock, but I'd like to test these data services as well).

On the technology side, the project uses `Angular: ^7.2.10` and `jest: ^23.6.0`.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that `DataService` is also a Service and I also tried to add it to the `providers` in the `beforeEach()` and I still get the same error (`Unexpected value 'HttpClientModule'...`). As shown below

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      HttpClientTestingModule,
      TranslateModule.forRoot(),
      LoggerModule.forRoot({ level: NgxLoggerLevel.ERROR, serverLoggingUrl: 'api/logging', serverLogLevel: NgxLoggerLevel.ERROR }),
    ],
    providers: [
      DataService,
      UserDataService
    ]
  });
});
```

Also to give a bit more overview of the `DataService`, here's a strip down version of it.

```
export class DataService {
  constructor(protected http: HttpClient, protected logger: NGXLogger, protected translate: TranslateService) {}

  get<T>(id?: string, options?: HttpOptions): Observable<T> {
    const caller = findCaller(new Error());
    const uriWithId = id ? `/${id}` : '';
    const requestUrl = this.addGlobalQueryParams(`${this.url}${uriWithId}`);
    this.logger.debug(`DataService - GET method [${caller}] - START - URL:: ${requestUrl}`);

    return this.http.get<T>(requestUrl, options).pipe(map((response: any) => {
      this.logger.debug(`DataService - GET method [${caller}] - END - URL:: ${requestUrl} - Response:: `, response);
      return response;
    }));
  }

  getAll<T>(url?: string, options?: HttpOptions): Observable<T> {
    const caller = findCaller(new Error());
    if (url) {
      this.logger.debug(`DataService - POST method [${caller}] - START - URL:: `, url);
      return this.http.post<T>(url).pipe(map((response: any) => {
        this.logger.debug(`DataService - POST method [${caller}] - END - URL:: ${url} - Response:: `, response);
        return response;
      }));
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I guess what I'm looking for is how to Unit Test an Extended Class, which was actually asked in the Angular repo [here](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/533) but was never answered and closed because it wasn't an issue but more of a question.

Comment: I'm guessing you `DataService` is a also a service. Then you are missing that from your `providers` closure.

Comment: Yes `DataService` is also a Service, and if you mean adding it to the `providers` array in the `beforeEach`, I already tried that and I still get the same error. I'll add that comment to my question.

Comment: but technically what the code does is to use DI in extended service (like `UserDataService` which has the `@Injectable()`) and the `DataService` gets all instances from there (there's no `@Injectable()` in that service since it receives them from the `super(service1, service2, service3)` call). I'm not sure how to reflect that in the `TestBed`, does that make any sense?

Comment: Its not related to the error but to build an proper test implementation.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean, where should I add the `DataService`?

Comment: You have to add it as a provider and it is not the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't need to do the following in your test.

```
 providers: [
   UserDataService
 ]
```

Since you are testing the `UserDataService` itself, doing the following after setting the TestBed should be enough.

```
dataService = TestBed.inject(UserDataService); //TestBed.get(UserDataService);
```

The other thing to change would be making your base class injectable.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {...}
```

I know it sounds stupid, but apparently angular DI seems to need that too.